# Trying to keep the image size inside of the card FAILS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am making some cards with an image in the shape of a water drop...

I am not managing to keep the shape of the drop correct for all screen resolutions. Any help will be appreciated.

Working example: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-card-function-uwpjo?file=/src/styles/styles.css)

Comment: When on small screen, image and content both take 100% width, so use `display: flex , flex-direction: row` or `display: inline-block`. After that you can do styling on the basis of `screen-width`

Comment: @HarishSharma where i pu that...? you have any exemple?

Comment: Add it in the parent. In your case `CardImage` & `CardContent` are children of `Card`. So `display: flex, flex-direction: `row` will go to `Card`

Comment: @HarishSharma can you view the code again? I think it looks weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MediaQueries package to work with different screen resoultions. Other choices are also available but it might help you.